# Variable not defined when I called a global variable

Tags: python

I'm trying to Globalize the `msg.topic` with `test` and then use it in showdata function. But when I called the `test`  variable inside my `showdata` function, it show me `"name 'test' is not defined"`Does anyone have any idea on this issue? Thanks in advance.

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt_client
import random


broker = 'localhost'
port = 1883
topic = "Wind"
# generate client ID with pub prefix randomly
client_id = f'python-mqtt-{random.randint(0, 100)}'
# username = 'emqx'
# password = 'public'


def connect_mqtt() -> mqtt_client:
    def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
        if rc == 0:
            print("Connected to MQTT Broker!")
        else:
            print("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc)

    client = mqtt_client.Client(client_id)
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.connect(broker, port)
    return client


def subscribe(client: mqtt_client):
    def on_message(client, userdata, msg, request):
        print(f"Received `{msg.payload.decode()}` from `{msg.topic}` topic")
        global test

        test = msg.topic

    client.subscribe(topic)
    client.on_message = on_message

def showdata(request):
    context = test
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'data': context})

def run():
    client = connect_mqtt()
    subscribe(client)
    client.loop_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: You should initialize the `test` variable on the upper side of code (under the imports). You may set the `None` into that variable first.

Comment: If the `on_message` function hasn't been called yet then the variable doesn't exist yet when you try and use it.

Comment: You have to delcare `text` as a `global text` in the main code & in any function that you use it

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the global variable in your upper scope like this:

```
broker = 'localhost'
port = 1883
topic = "Wind"
# generate client ID with pub prefix randomly
client_id = f'python-mqtt-{random.randint(0, 100)}'
# username = 'emqx'
# password = 'public'
test = None
```

Then you can use it in your function as expected.